# override angular class variable in a service import

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a angualar4 RestService exported, I need to override baseUrl to places where I import it.

```
   @Injectable()
    export class RestService {

      // needs to be more dynamic this should be changed later to use http or https
      // depending on if it is available
      private baseUrl: string = "/api/v1.0/";



    }
```

========importing it in Different file and using it in constructor=========

```
import {RestService} from '../../../../services/';

constructor(protected rest: RestService) {}
// I would like to change baseUrl to "/api/v2.0/" as needed.
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be of public access type as below,

```
  public baseUrl: string = "/api/v1.0/";
```

Some where in the component

```
this.service.baseUrl = '/api/v2.0/';
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/PJ8Q1MBNnswwrgw9qyVC?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to read your question. Do you like to have different urls used in different components? If so making baseurl public wont help since the injectable service is the same instance for all. If you like to have a base config that could be amended if needed you have to implement that logic.

```
import { Http } from '@angular/http';

export interface RestConfig {
  name: string;
  baseUrl: string;
  enableHttps: boolean;
}

export interface RestConfigCollection {
  data: Array<RestConfig>;
}

@Injectable()
export class RestService {
  private configCollection: RestConfigCollection;

  constructor(private _http: Http) {
    const baseConfig = <RestConfig> {
      name: "default";
      baseUrl: "/api/v1.0/";
      enableHttps: false;
    }
    this.configCollection = <RestConfigCollection> {
      data: [];
    }
    this.configCollection.push(baseConfig);
  }

  public registerConfig(config: RestConfig): void {
    this.configCollection.push(config);
  }

  private getConfigByIdentifier(name: string): RestConfig {
    for (const config of this.configCollection) {
      if (config.name === name) {
        return config;
      }
    }
    return this.getConfigByIdentifier("default");
  }

  public callRestPostWithConfig(identifier: string, callback: Function, postBody: string): any {
    const config = this.getConfigByIdentifier(identifier);
    return this._http.post(config.baseUrl, postBody, {}).subscribe(
      data => {
        const responseData = JSON.parse(data['foo']);
        callback(responseData);
      }, (err: HttpErrorResponse) => {}
  );
}
```

This is an incomplete draft, but I am sure you see where this is heading. In your component using the service you would register the config for that component with the service and later using that identifier.

Helps? Any thoughts on the approach by readers?

Answer (score 0):

Have a method to handle this (in `RestService`)

```
public setBaseUrl(url: string): void {
    this.baseUrl = url;
}
```

then call it:

```
this.rest.setBaseUrl('/api/v2.0/');
```